# How to start php7.3-fpm on Debian 10.3? Error: Failed to start The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager

Tags: php, debian

With a fresh installation of Debian 10.3 I tried to install php-fpm, but it wouldn't configure properly.

```
$ sudo apt install php-fpm
```

Threw this:

```
(...)   
Detected unsafe path transition / → /run during canonicalization of /run.
Job for php7.3-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php7.3-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.3-fpm, action "start" failed.
● php7.3-fpm.service - The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.3-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-03-10 12:03:31 -03; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.3(8)
  Process: 7111 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.3 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
 Main PID: 7111 (code=exited, status=78)
 (...)
```

It also complains about a `libapache2-mod-php7.3` dependency, but I don't want to use Apache.

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a folder for php within `/var/run`

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/php
sudo apt install --reinstall php-fpm
```

Comment: after install iRedMail and restart server. dont start php fpm. ites fixed just by `mkdir /var/run/php`